# How debug spark dropduplicate and join function calls?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is some table with duplicated rows. I am trying to reduce duplicates and stay with latest `my_date` (if there are
rows with same `my_date` it is no matter which one to use)

```
val dataFrame = readCsv()
  .dropDuplicates("my_id", "my_date")
  .withColumn("my_date_int", $"my_date".cast("bigint"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{min, max, grouping}

val aggregated = dataFrame
    .groupBy(dataFrame("my_id").alias("g_my_id"))
  .agg(max(dataFrame("my_date_int")).alias("g_my_date_int"))

val output = dataFrame.join(aggregated, dataFrame("my_id") === aggregated("g_my_id") && dataFrame("my_date_int") === aggregated("g_my_date_int"))
    .drop("g_my_id", "g_my_date_int")
```

But after this code I when grab `distinct my_id` I get about `3000` less than in source table. What a reason can be?

how to debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

After doing drop duplicates do a except of this data frame with the original data frame this should give some insight on the rows which are additionally getting dropped . Most probably there are certain null or empty values for those columns which are being considered duplicates.